# What is the difference between optical flow and motion vectors?

Tags: vector, computer-vision, motion, opticalflow

I am exploring the field of video analysis and computer vision.
In a certain research paper i found that motion vectors are a better option than optical flow for video summarization task.
I am unable to find the difference between these two.
Any help is appreciated..